# Checking Descendants for matches C#

Tags: c#, regex, filtering, html-agility-pack

I'm working on a project where i basically scrape content from a web page using html agility pack until i get the nods i need using the code below

```
foreach (HtmlNode tr in bodyNode.SelectNodes("//tr")){
    //tr.Descendants("span").Where(n => n.InnerHtml.Contains("display:none")).ToList().
    //ForEach(n => n.Remove()); ;
}
```

So after each loop i get html content similar to what i have pasted below

http://pastebin.com/DLVykNXU

What i need to do is to check the node for matches. Basically i need to remove the

```
<span style="display:none">what ever value here</span>
div style="display:none">what ever value here</div>
```

and some other div's & Spans with different different ID & Class names. But the code I've written above seems to fail me since it deletes the entire nod without deleting only the content within the tag and tags it self.

I will be very thankful if a expert could help me with this, i'm still a student learning C# so i'm sorry if the codes aren't perfect.
Thank you.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to extract from the above code? It seems like you're trying to parse proxies from some pages (when seeing `Brazil` and `High +KA`), but I can't find the proxy & port in your code.

Comment: @OscarMederos : Its tricky, try removing all the display none elements. you get the proxy and port :D

Comment: what is the proxy & port for the HTML you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said... you'll have to do some tricks.

```
foreach (var tr in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")) {
    var style = tr.SelectSingleNode(".//style");
    //Find the classes and ids with {display:none}
    var matches = Regex.Matches(style.InnerText, @"(\.|#)(.+?)\s*{\s*display\s*:\s*none");

    //Here we will store the classes & ids we'll need to remove
    List<string> classes = new List<string>();
    List<string> ids = new List<string>();

    //Storing the ids and classes
    foreach (Match m in matches) {
        var type = m.Groups[1].Value;
        if (type == ".")
        {
            classes.Add(m.Groups[2].Value);
        }
        else {
            ids.Add(m.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }

    foreach (var n in tr.SelectNodes(".//*")) {
        if (Remove(n, classes, ids)) {
            n.Remove();
        }
    }

    var proxy = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[2]/span").InnerText;
    var port = tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[3]").InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', ' ');
}
```

and have the following method

```
//Remove the ones that have {display:none}, and the ones with the ids & classes provided.
static bool Remove(HtmlNode x, IList<string> classes, IList<string> ids) {
    var classAttr = x.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
    var idAttr = x.GetAttributeValue("id", "");
    return (x.Name == "span" && x.GetAttributeValue("style", "") == "display:none") ||
           (x.Name == "div" && x.GetAttributeValue("style", "") == "display:none") ||
           (x.Name == "span" && classes.Contains(classAttr)) ||
           (x.Name == "div" && classes.Contains(classAttr)) ||
           (x.Name == "span" && ids.Contains(idAttr)) ||
           (x.Name == "id" && ids.Contains(idAttr)) ||
           (x.Name == "style");
}
```

You could add more filters in the `Remove` method. Since you're writing C# code, you can check anything you want there, not only related to *XPath* expressions.

That code gave me the following list of proxies:

```
190.199.36.220:8080
177.139.137.107:3128
103.247.23.90:8080
222.124.130.203:8080
14.140.241.242:8080
175.103.37.10:8080
110.77.183.113:3128
54.243.51.203:8118
200.90.179.90:8080
213.152.173.137:8080
187.17.212.162:8080
62.201.207.14:8080
77.123.76.178:8080
189.76.212.254:3128
89.218.224.234:9090
221.179.173.170:8080
187.84.56.42:3128
118.99.79.13:8080
211.86.157.110:3128
189.38.3.122:3128
2.135.238.178:9090
2.135.238.2:9090
122.50.38.128:3128
217.11.185.251:3128
82.200.254.2:9090
37.59.82.253:8080
83.111.38.131:3128
85.118.227.76:3128
182.30.249.13:8080
124.88.154.3:6673
111.13.87.150:80
190.85.37.90:8080
219.117.232.133:3128
211.100.47.138:8990
46.32.21.195:8080
107.18.121.126:8080
118.97.191.203:8080
119.195.32.211:3128
2.133.92.242:9090
202.164.217.18:8080
222.124.214.194:3128
79.140.17.253:3128
61.138.104.30:1080
201.45.116.138:3128
190.98.209.168:3128
190.204.222.183:8080
200.199.173.122:3128
197.159.16.58:8080
223.4.233.164:3128
212.93.195.229:3128
```

Comment: Thanks , Code is perfect but we need to extract the content inside <style></style> tags and search them for display:none property and remove the span and div's with the matched class or id.

Full Source : http://pastebin.com/5H0khYr7

Thanks.

Comment: I made a function , http://pastebin.com/2n4cHwiq
Waiting to see your solution.

Thanks

Comment: @DriverBoy An advise for the future: Try to identify what exactly is your problem (what isn't working), and ask that. Then, based on the answers, try to solve your problem. My point is: don't expect to receive full working answers like mine in the future, since it doesn't really help you (although you think it does). *Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime* ;)

Comment: I get the point , i never expect someone to post the full answer but thank you, i really appreciate you doing that. I only post a question on SOF when i get stuck while trying to archive something and the community has always helped me.

Thank you Oscar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the content, it would be easier, if you just select it with

```
"//tr//span[contains(@style, 'display:none')]/text()"
```

Similarly for `span`s with a specific `id` or `class` attribute

```
"//tr//span[@id='123']/text()"
```

or

```
"//tr//span[contains(@class, 'cl17')]/text()"
```

If you want, you can combine all these conditions

```
"//tr//span[contains(@style, 'display:none') or @id='123' or contains(@class, 'cl17')]/text()"
```